# How to test for the effects of plant community composition on insect community composition whilst controlling for geographic distance?

Tags: r, regression, pca, ecology, correspondence-analysis

I'm trying to test for the effects of plant community composition on insect community composition using ordination, but I need to control for geographic distance.

I know CCA can handle three matrices simultaneously, but since I have more plant species than sites (60 sites), CCA becomes inappropriate (see Ter Braak & Schaffers 2004). I have tried cocorrespondence analysis, but I cannot incorporate geographic distance.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem (other than using Mantel tests)?

I do my analyses in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an RDA instead of a CCA. It's more appropriated than CCA for partial ordination see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Joseph_Bennett/publication/227702291_Gilbert_B._and_J._R._Bennett._Partitioning_variation_in_ecological_communities_do_the_numbers_add_up_Journal_of_Applied_Ecology/links/0912f50b2c15d6519a000000.pdf).

For the spatial modelling, you could use Moran Eigenvector Maps, see [this paper](http://adn.biol.umontreal.ca/~numericalecology/Reprints/Dray_et_al_Ecol_Monogr_2012.pdf).

Then, your model would be `vegan::varpart(insect_com~plant_com+MEM)`.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I think I still have the same issue with RDA as CCA (see Ter Braak & Schaffers 2004) where the analysis becomes inappropriate due to too many plant species included (more than sites). It treats each plant species as a separate variable (if I understand correctly) and you thus end up with more predictor variables than data points (sites). I need something that treats the plant community matrix as a unit and not as separate variables.